# error de node :module.js : 538 throw err

Tags: javascript, nodejs

129/5000
Realmente no sé qué tipo de problema es, pero aparentemente cada vez que quiero usar el js no funciona 
.Gracias por responder.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Answer (score 0):

Tal cual lo indica el error en la terminal, estás tratando de ejecutar un archivo que no existe, dado que intentas acceder al archivo 'D:/paginaWeb1/menu-a.js' pero tu archivo .js esta en el directorio 'D:/paginaWeb1/js/menu-a.js'.

**Para solucionar esto puedes usar las siguientes opciones:**

1. `$ node js/menu-a.js`;
2. `$ cd js; node menu-a.js`